# how to close two nested modals open in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, modal-dialog

Hope you are doing well..
I'm having one small problem in react js and I'm too much confused in this, I'm having one page where I'm opening one modal and inside that modal I'm opening second modal, so the problem here is If I'm clicking outside of the second modal then it will close second modal and it will go to first modal and for first modal If I'm clicking outside then it will go to the main page, so my requirement is if I'm having second modal open and I click outside of the second modal then I should reach to main page not in first modal, I'm attaching JS fiddle link here, you open that link and click on the first modal button and then click on the second modal button and after that click outside of second modal then I should see main page not first modal open, then how to implement this functionality in react js, I can't share my official code here because it's private property but I created my own code with html and bootstrap so please help me to solve this problem using javascript or react js, Any suggestion will be very helpful.
Fiddle link

````
```
http://jsfiddle.net/unto9g0L/
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using modal inside a modal? It's a bad solution. You should render two modals and control their open property.

example in react:

```
import Modal from './Modal'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [firstModal, setFirstModal] = useState(false)
  const [secondModal, setSecondModal] = useState(false)

  // I don't know context of your app, but you can use variable in close handle
  const handleCloseFirstModal = (shouldOpenSecond) => {
    setFirstModal(false)
    if (shouldOpenSecond === true) {
      setSecondModal(true)
    }
  }

  const handleCloseSecondModal = () => {
    setSecondModal(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
     <Modal open={firstModal} onRequestClose={handleCloseFirstModal} />
     <Modal open={secondModal} onRequestClose={handleCloseSecondModal} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Actually the modal is opening inside modal only and it is already implemented in project, so I need to change the behaviour like If I click outside of the modal 2 then it should close both modal together and then it should go to main page not to modal 1

Comment: @beginner_coder so change close handle of the second modal to close first too.